# Accessing a data attribute in the first/last child element of a parent element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently trying to implement a refreshing post feed, and have something like the following going on, trying to grab data-pid out of a child element:

HTML:

```
<div id="postFeed">
    <div data-pid="6">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    alert($("#postFeed:first-child").attr("data-pid"));
    ...
});
```

I've tried several different methods, but all I ever get back is 'undefined'. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logic issue with the current script.

What you should be using is -

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    alert($("#postFeed").children(":first").attr("data-pid"));
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecnprj6L/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Please understand that the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector selects all elements that are the first child of their parent. But here `#postFeed` is not the child you want to target, you want to target the `div` inside it. So, you just need to use `:first-child` selector on that child element.

Also, instead of using `.attr("data-pid")` you can simply use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. The `.data()` method allows us to read data previously associated with DOM elements. Also, we can retrieve several distinct values for a single element one at a time, or as a set like:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  console.log( $("#postFeed div:first-child").data("pid") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="postFeed">
  <div data-pid="6">
    A
  </div>
  <div data-pid="8">
    B
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code it **$("#postFeed:first-child")** means first child of div with id **postFeed**.

```
 $("#postFeed:first-child").attr("data-pid")
```

Instead find inside postfeed div and this can be done by using following code.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    alert($("#postFeed div:first-child").attr("data-pid"));
})
```